# Get the array index from annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Hi I would like to get the index number when the user taps on the annotation. I have the following code..

```
class ShopLocation: NSObject, MKAnnotation{

 var identifier = "Shop location"
 var title: String?
 var subtitle: String?
 var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(name:String,lat:CLLocationDegrees,long:CLLocationDegrees,addInfo:String){
        title = name
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
        subtitle = addInfo
    }

}
    class LocationList: NSObject {


        var shop = [ShopLocation]()

          override init(){
            shop += [ShopLocation(name:"t1", lat:35.673647,long:139.727686,addInfo:"info")]

            shop += [ShopLocation(name:"t2", lat:35.671928,long:139.760815,addInfo:"info")]

            shop += [ShopLocation(name:"t3", lat:35.713232,long:139.793467,addInfo:"info")]
    }
```

The annotations are displayed on a map. I would like to get the index for example if t1 is tapped I get an index of 1.

I don't know what to write in

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    LocationList().shop.index(of: )

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need the index or do you need to access the `ShopLocation` instance that maps to the annotation view?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need the index of shop array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `ShopLocation` already conforms to `MKAnnotation`, if not then make it conform and pass it to `MKAnnotationView`'s initializer. This will make it available in the `delegate` method, via `view.annotation`

Now that you have access to the `ShopLocation` instance, there are two solutions that come to my mind for finding it's index in the `shop`

1. Conform to `Equatable` - this will enable the `firstIndex(of:)` method of `Array` (actually of `Collection` to which `Array` conforms)

   ```
    extension ShopLocation: Equatable {
        static func ==(lhs: ShopLocation, rhs: ShopLocation) -> Bool {
            // place here the conditions for two instances to be equal
        }

    // ... later in the code

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        guard let shopLocation = view.annotation as? ShopLocation else {
            // this early returns if the annotation is not a shop location,
            // if you don't wan't that you can use an if-let instead
            return
        }
        let index = LocationList().shop.firstIndex(of: shopLocation)
        // do what you need with the index
    }
   ```
2. Use the `firstIndex(where:)` method of `Array` (again, actually of `Collection` :)

   ```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        guard let shopLocation = view.annotation as? ShopLocation else {
            // this early returns if the annotation is not a shop location,
            // if you don't wan't that you can use an if-let instead
            return
        }
        let index = LocationList().shop.firstIndex(where: { shopLocation in
            return // same conditions as for the Equatable
        })
        // do what you need with the index
    }
   ```

Personally, I'd recommend approach #1, even Apple recommends conforming value types to Equatable. Conforming to `Equatable` helps with code reduction, and enables lots of other functions besides the `index(of:)` mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let annotation = view.annotation else {
        return
    }
    for (index, item) in LocationList().shop.enumerated() {
        if let title = view.annotation?.title {
            if item.name! == title! {
                print(index)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Those are a lot of forced unwraps :)

Comment: Hello  thank you for your code butI get an error saying shoplocation has no member name at  `item.name! == title!`

Comment: @Cristik Use optional binding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        var index = shops.index(of: view.annotation! as! ShopLocation)!
    }
```

Did the job for me.

Comment: Just a note that you are doing  a lot of forced casts here, which have the potential of crashing the app if later on the conditions change. I'd recommend using `if-let`, or `guard-let` constructs instead.